# Spring RestTemplate character encoding for "#"

Tags: java, spring, spring-rest

I'm really having a tough time with some character encoding issues with "#".  I'm trying to "GET" from a url "URL/path/#, with literally the "#" in front of the param.  The endpoint is expecting the character encoded value for "#", or "%23".  However, the RestTemplate is either a) not encoding "#" which results in other exceptions from the API (the API really wants "%23" and not "#", or b) double encoding the "%". How can I use the RestTemplate to literally send "%23".

The code is pretty simple:

```
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntityWithSomeAuthHeader, 
    new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeObject>() {});
```

url is as described above...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hope not to late ;)

try  this one:

```
URI uri = new URI(url);
restTemplate.exchange(uri, HttpMethod.GET, httpEntityWithSomeAuthHeader, 
new ParameterizedTypeReference<SomeObject>() {});
```

And important, use %23 in url param. It's seems that if you use # (with string or uri) it discard all after... but with %23 and "new URI" it put in query (inside uri as %23) and the server decode as #.

Hope it's help ;)

PD: A co-worker remembered me this https://xkcd.com/979/ when we saw your answerd question ;) and now we have the answerd